# $C_0(X)$ is a subspace of $C_b(X)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm doing some self-study on Banach spaces and this statement came up in a proposition: Let $X$ be locally compact and $C_0(X)$ be the set of all continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$ such that for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\{x:|f(x)|\geq \varepsilon\}$ is compact. Then $C_0(X)$ is Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|_{C_b(X)}$.

First, I need to show that $C_0(X)\subset C_b(X)$, but I'm a little unsure of my proof, so I'm posting to see what is incorrect about the logic. Since $A_{\varepsilon}:=\{x:|f(x)|\geq \varepsilon\}$ is compact, $\cap_{\varepsilon=1}^{\infty}A_{\varepsilon}=\{x:|f(x)|=\infty\}$ is compact. Therefore, $f(\cap_{\varepsilon=1}^{\infty}A_{\varepsilon})$ is compact. So, we can find $M$ such that $|f(y)|\leq M$ for all $y\in \cap_{\varepsilon=1}^{\infty}A_{\varepsilon}=\{x:|f(x)|=\infty\}$. Hence, $\{x:|f(x)|=\infty\}=\emptyset$. Do you believe the proof for containment is sound, or is there something big I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am slightly confused about the notation $\{x : |f(x)| =\infty\}$ notation. Indeed, a function could be infinity nowhere and yet be unbounded, the best example being $f(x) = x$ on $\mathbb R$. Next, what is $|f(\cap_\epsilon A_\epsilon)|$? You have said it is some compact set, but we want to show it is empty, if at all. So there are issues.

The answer is even simpler. If $f \in C_0(X)$, then fix $\epsilon > 0$, so that the set $\{x : |f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$ is compact. Now, every continuous function attains its maximum and minimum on a compact set, therefore so does $|f(x)|$ on $\{x : |f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$. But on the rest, $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. Hence, $|f(x)|$ is bounded everywhere on $X$, therefore $f \in C_b(X)$.

EDIT :  We claim that $f  \in C_b(X)$. We will do this using notation established by the OP himself.

Indeed, let $f$ be unbounded. Then there exist $x_n \in X$ so that $|f(x_n)| > n$. Now, note that $x_n \in A_{n}$.

Hence, $A_n$ are non-empty and compact for all $n$, and are contained in the compact space $A_1$. By the finite intersection property of non-empty compact sets, some element $x \in A_n$ for all $n$, which is a contradiction since $f(x)$ is some fixed real number so $|f(x)| < n$ for some $n$. Consequently , it follows that $A_n$ is empty for some $n$, and hence $f$ is bounded.

Comment: I think I meant that $\cap_{\varepsilon}A_{\varepsilon}$ is the set where $f$ is unbounded, not that it necessarily equals infinity. Would you agree that is what $\cap_{\varepsilon}A_{\varepsilon}$ is? Thank you for your answer, by the way, it's a much simpler (and correct) argument.

Comment: See, the point is that $f$ is real valued, so it cannot *equal* infinity anywhere. So when you write the set $\cap A_\epsilon$, and want to show it is empty, then what I am trying to tell you is that *it is already empty* by definition of $f$. Furthermore, $f$ is bounded is *not the same* as saying that $\cap A_\epsilon$  is empty.$f$ is bounded would be said as : $A_\epsilon$ is *non-empty* for all $\epsilon$, but this is not the same as $\cap A_{\epsilon} = \phi$. So what I am saying is that you started out to prove an obvious statement, and hence required correction.

Comment: Also, I highly appreciate your efforts, so I upvote your question as well!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Cheers!

Comment: You are welcome!  By the way, I just found another proof, which comes from the argument you have set up in your attempt. I will edit the answer to add that as well.

Comment: Edit done. You may notice.

Comment: I appreciate you helping me this much. It really has helped me understand this topic more, even if it is an obvious result.

Comment: You are welcome! I actually wish to add a few more things for "completeness", which I shall do so in due course. I will inform you. I take it you are doing a functional analysis course?

Comment: I've been reading about PDEs with a view from functional analysis. It's not a course, more of an interest.

Comment: Good idea. It so happens that I've also done some study in PDEs, more like PDE on manifolds, if you like.